# Error: declaration does not declare

Tags: c++, object, header

Hello I´m new to C++ and come from Java so i did try to build a little game when i did try to make a public ItemRegister or anything out of it it did not work. It is my intention to have only one of it and it needs public access.

Game.h

```
#pragma once
#include "ItemRegister.h"


class Game{
    static ItemRegister register;

public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
private:
    Item test;
};
```

ItemRegister.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Item.h"

using namespace std;
class ItemRegister{
    public:
    ItemRegister();
    ~ItemRegister();

    void registerItem(Item newItem);
    Item getItem(string name);
    Item getItemByID(int id);
    int getItemID(string name);

    int getRegisteredItemMax();
private:
    vector<Item> registeredItems;

};
```

The ItemRegister register throws always an error where ever it is.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: _"The ItemRegister register throws always an error where ever it is."_ Which error is thrown exactly please? Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27594814/edit) to add this essential information!

Comment: Is `ItemRegister` throwing an error, or the fact that you never initialized your `static ItemRegister`?

Comment: Error: declaration does not declare anything on the ItemRegister and Error: invalid storage class for a class member

Comment: @David Good spot and guess. Let's see upon OP is going to clarify.

Comment: Could also be that register is on the wrong side.

Comment: @AlexanderH _"Error: declaration does not declare ..."_ Verbatim, and in your question please, as I've requested.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ renamed the title to what you requested.
atDavid what do you mean with on the wrong side

Comment: @AlexanderH Also `register` is a keyword, name it something else.

Comment: @AlexanderH I requested, you to show the verbatim error message you get at compile or runtime into your question. What's so hard about doing this just now?

Comment: @Barry thanks i don´t know the language and every keyword it has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`register`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register) is a C++ keyword, you thus cannot use it as a variable name.

```
class Game{
    static ItemRegister register;
                        ^^^^^^^^
```

You can find a complete list of C++ keywords [here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)